# What is the best way to call JS functions from Dust.js templates?

Tags: dust.js

Let's say I have a partial template 'render_box' which is being called dynamically based on key {widget} in multiple places -

e.g 
`{"widget":"box"}
 {>"render_{widget}":. /}`

and I want to trigger jQuery event each time this 'render_box' finishes.
can I just include SCRIPT tag in the partial? I have read that this is [not good practice](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Reusable-UI-Dust-modules) due to performance. any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to create your own helper function.

Comment: As simon suggested, I'd write some custom helper (which are nothing more than javascript functions). Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858271/how-to-append-html-into-section-in-dust-js/24445683#24445683